# Laravel unavailable route not showing 404 page

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am having following routes. There is no route match to `/admin` but this route is showing a blank page and not showing 404 page.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth:admin'], function () {

    Route::GET('/home','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');

    Route::get('/list-registered-users', 'AdminController@registeredusers')->name('listregisteredusers');
    Route::get('registeredusersgetall','AdminController@registeredusersgetall')->name('registeredusersgetall');
    Route::POST('user/change_status','AdminController@change_status')->name('change_status');
    Route::resource('user','AdminController');
 });
```

I have seen `php artisan route:list` no route match found for `/admin` but why is this showing a blank page
Note:resepose code is also showing 200